# using like operator in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

The following stored procedure gives me output when I provide the whole song name e.g `hello` in my case. How to write a stored procedure such that when I pass `hel` to the variable `@songName`, it gives me all the songs starting with characters `hel`

```
create procedure sp_searchsong
@songName varchar(50)
as
begin
    select * from songs where songName = @songName
end

execute sp_searchsong @songName = 'hello'
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `like`:

```
create procedure sp_searchsong (
    @songName varchar(50)
) as
begin
    select * 
    from songs
    where songName like @songName + '%';
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was just confused how to use `like` operator. Did not know that you have to add a `+`.
Many Thanks

Comment: @UsamaTahir . . . The `+` is used here as a string concatenation operator in SQL Server.  It is adding the wildcard to the `LIKE` pattern string.